# Message box showing up when it's not supposed to?

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a program where the user enters the month and gets back the number of days. If the user enters something that isn't a month, it should say something like "Please enter a valid month" but only if it isn't a real month. The problem is the message box is showing up all the time, even when a valid month is entered.

```
Dim monthname() As String = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"}
Dim monthdays() As String = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}

For i = 0 To monthname.GetUpperBound(0)
    If monthname(i) = TextBox1.Text Then
        TextBox2.Text = monthname(i) & " has " & monthdays(i) & " days"
    End If
Next

If String.Compare(TextBox1.Text, monthname(11)) <> 0 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a vaild month")
End If
```

Comment: you are using the wrong `String.Compare` overload if you want `April` to match `april` or `aPRiL`

Comment: You need to add the declaration `Option Strict On` to the top of your code. The declaration of `monthsdays` will then fail, but it's easy to fix and it'll make your code easy to work with and less bug-prone.

Comment: I'm disappointed that people feel the need to downvote a question that has been very presented in a very clear and concise manner. Downvotes should be for poorly asked questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if the textbox contained any valid month name, you can't just check to see it it is equal to the last month. Instead, you can declare a Boolean variable (called found) that will default to False, then set it to True if the textbox matches one of the month names. I think the following code does what you want. It does a case-insensitive comparison to the month name; if you want to reject "may" and "MAY" and only accept "May", change the True to False in the String.Compare statement.

```
Dim monthName() As String = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"}
Dim monthDays() As Integer = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}
Dim found As Boolean

For i As Integer = 0 To monthName.GetUpperBound(0)
    If String.Compare(monthName(i), TextBox1.Text, True) = 0 Then
        TextBox2.Text = monthName(i) & " has " & monthDays(i).ToString & " days"
        found = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If Not found Then MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid month")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're comparing the entered value only against `monthname(11)`. You need to run a loop and compare against every value.

Comment: I'm a little confused, what do you mean run a loop? Like a do until loop?

Comment: your `For i = 0 To...` is a loop.  you need to do the same thing with the textbox if you are trying to find `TextBox1.Text` in the array like your classmates are

Comment: @DaveMatthews The current code compares what you entered to `monthname(11)` which is "December". If you don't know what a loop is or how to use it to fix this problem, then StackOverflow isn't the best place to get your answers; it's not really a mentoring place and questions that require people to teach you a bit about basic programming first are not generally well-received. That's probably why your question got downvoted. I wish I could suggest a more suitable place, but I'm afraid I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you go about this slightly differently.

Rather than work with two arrays that you have to manually type into your code I would build a dictionary of month data first and use that.

Start with this:

```
Dim months = _
    Enumerable _
        .Range(0, 12) _
        .Select(Function(n) New DateTime(2015, n + 1, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1.0)) _
        .ToDictionary( _
            Function(x) x.ToString("MMMM").ToLowerInvariant(), _
            Function(x) x.Day)
```

This gives you a dictionary mapping the names of the months to the number of days.

[image: dictionary]

Now you can code the rest of your method rather simply like this:

```
Dim entered = TextBox1.Text.Trim().ToLowerInvariant()

If months.ContainsKey(entered) Then
    Dim proper = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(entered)
    TextBox2.Text = String.Format("{0} has {1} days", proper, months(entered))
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a vaild month")
End If
```